# On Enter key press processTabkey() not working

Tags: c#, key, devexpress, keydown, enter

I have a form which navigates records through prev and next buttons. We can add a new entry by clicking new button. Prev,Next and new all are redirected to same form, prev and next populates form whereas new keep all entries empty and we can enter data. I have kept keypreview =true for this form and handled keydown().

```
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
             ProcessTabKey(true);
        }
```

It works for prev and next key navigated form. But on pressing new and trying to press enter, its not working. Please suggest how to make this work.

Comment: Can you show a more extensive part of the code.

Comment: private void TxtVrNo_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Shift == false) & (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter))
            {
                ProcessTabKey(true);
            }
      }                                         I have pasted this keydown event for all textboxes properties->events->keydown. Since its calling processtabkey it should work. its working for prev,next so that will not be a issue

Comment: Hi, An update. If I try processtabkey for each text box it works. But for prev,next txtVrno_keydown works for all textboxes. Why its not working for new

Answer (score 0):

use form keydown and type the textbox you want to write

`Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) { ProcessTabKey(true); console.write(e.Key) }`

Comment: Got resolved. I need to check whether the voucherno is the last voucherno and if so some code need not be executed. This was not done earlier.